# Java Servlet как получить GET параметры из URL

Tags: javascript, jsp, url, servlet, get

На jsp странице при нажатии на ссылку

```
<a onclick="return setAttr('user','Oleg')">Oleg</a>
```

JavaScript код :

```
function setAttr(prmName,val){
var res = '';
var d = location.href.split("#")[0].split("?");
var base = d[0];
var query = d[1];
if(query) {
    var params = query.split("&");
    for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var keyval = params[i].split("=");
        if(keyval[0] != prmName) {
            res += params[i] + '&';
        }
    }
}
res += prmName + '=' + val;
window.history.pushState(null, null, base + '?' + res);
return false;
}
```

задает параметры в URL, `localhost://bla-bla/index.jsp?user=Oleg`.
Затем, когда через форму по сабмиту я перехожу на сервлет :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponsу response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String name = request.getParameter("user");
}
```

После чего вылетает `NullPointerException`, почему??

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `getParameter` и `setParameter` лучше использовать `getAttribute` и `setAttribute`. Ну и не забываем о приведении типов.

Например:

```
String name = request.getAttribute("user").toString();
```

Кроме того, Ваш способ перенаправления (через `window.history.pushState`) корректно работать работать не будет. Во всяком случае, без установки остальных параметров.

Используйте `location`.

```
window.location = "http://site.ru"
```

Comment: все равно null, мб параметры из URL не доходят до сервлета

Comment: ну да, не мешало бы запрос проверить `request.getQueryString()`

Comment: request.getQueryString вернуло пустую строку((